# implicit intent fails to show app menu

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that is supposed to invoke an implicit intent and I have a target that I want to receive the intent. It always opens the default app. I am not sure where the error is. 
Here is the code:

```
private void startImplicitActivation() {
    Intent baseIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, CHOOSER_TEXT) ;
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
 }
```

and

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="http"/>
```

logcat

```
[2015-01-29 18:23:14 - IntentsLab] Android Launch!
[2015-01-29 18:23:14 - IntentsLab] adb is running normally.
[2015-01-29 18:23:14 - IntentsLab] Performing course.labs.intentslab.ActivityLoaderActivity activity launch
[2015-01-29 18:23:15 - IntentsLab] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'smallapp'
[2015-01-29 18:23:17 - IntentsLab] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2015-01-29 18:23:17 - IntentsLab] Starting activity course.labs.intentslab.ActivityLoaderActivity on device emulator-5554
[2015-01-29 18:23:21 - IntentsLab] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=course.labs.intentslab/.ActivityLoaderActivity }
[2015-01-29 18:23:21 - IntentsLab] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Comment: here is the log cat info

Comment: close the app in phone/emulator and then run again. Run the App in phone and not in emulator, because there will not be many applications installed to handle the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<intent-filter>` is not correct. Replace

```
<data android:mimeType="http"/>
```

with

```
<data android:scheme="http"/>
```

"http" is not a valid mime type, and probably not what you want anyway.